# How do I validate an instance of JSON schema against a swagger schema?

Tags: json, validation, go, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a JSON payload (request or response) and I want to validate that instance against a swagger schema that I have. How do I do that?

Please note that I am not trying to validate if my spec is an OpenAPI/Swagger spec.

I'd like to achieve this without the use of external JSON validators. I am also trying to achieve this in Go (specifically go-openapi)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a hold of the schema that defines your validation rules, that's typically stored in the swagger spec definition property.

And you need to get your model (json data structure, can be a map or a struct).
Here's an example:

```
var model models.User
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &model)

var spec *spec.Swagger = getSpec()
schema := spec.Definitions["User"]

if err := validate.AgainstSchema(schema, &model, strfmt.Default); err != nil {
  return err
}
```